# Overlay a UISegmentedControl over a SKSpriteNode

Tags: swift, metal, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm currently using Metal to create a game board with floating balloons; each balloon is a SKSpriteNode with an image of a balloon attached. The user touches and drags the balloon to a second balloon, merging the two. Exactly how they get merged is based on input from the user. I have a UISegmentedControl that pops up where the user selects one of four responses and the merge occurs. Currently, the UISegmentedControl pops up in the middle of the game board; however, I would like it to overlay on top of the first balloon instead.

I have tried this once the two balloons touch each other:

```
bubble1.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0) // Stopping the balloon

requestView.frame.origin.x = bubble1.position.x
requestView.frame.origin.y = bubble1.position.y
```

Where requestView is a UIView (with the same dimensions of the balloon) with various subviews (including the UISegmentedControl) and bubble1 is the SKSpriteNode (balloon).
However, when I add the requestView as a subview of the game board, it does not overlay on top of the SKSpriteNode (bubble1). In fact, each time I try it, it doesn't even seem to appear in the same space relative to the location of the bubble1.
Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: SpriteKit is not UIKit.  Stay away from UIKit stuff.  I don't even use `Timer` under SpriteKit.

Comment: I understand that; however, are you suggesting that I simply build a UISegmentedControl type item in SpriteKit?  That seems like a lot of work to replace something that's an easy add.  There should be some way I can correlate the location of the Sprite object and place the UIKit object over it, are you suggesting there really isn't?

Comment: Have you ever seen a game where there is a segment control in it?  You don't use UIKit stuff in a SpriteKit game.  Have a SpriteKit game design instead of a UIKit design.

Comment: Poor advice. There is no reason you can't use UIKit. I use Metal with an extensive UIKit interface, and since SpriteKit is just a wrapper for Metal I see no reason why you can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIKit` uses *screen* coordinates while `Metal` uses *clip-spaced* coordinates.

Here are functions that convert `UIKit` coordinates to `Metal`:

[Convert screen coordinates to Metal's Normalized Device Coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58293221/convert-screen-coordinates-to-metals-normalized-device-coordinates)

You will need to do the inverse to convert `Metal` to `UIKit`. Something like this:

```
func convertToScreenCoordinates(clipPos: CGPoint, viewSize: CGSize) -> CGPoint {
    let screenX = (clipPos.x + 1.0) * 0.5 * viewSize.width
    let screenY = (-clipPos.y + 1.0) * 0.5 * viewSize.height
    return CGPoint(x: screenX, y: screenY)
}
```

This may be helpful too: [translate between NSView and MTL drawable coordinates](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/47507)